# Express / Mongoose REST and middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

If you apply middleware to a rest POST call and you provide an array of JSON objects as the req.body will the middleware iterate through each object and run for each one or will it just run once for the entire request body?

Comment: It will run just once for the entire request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to write my middleware in a way that can handle arrays and iterate through by using: for ( var i in req.body ) {...}.

There is no documentation on this and down voting for no research effort is asinine.

The answer is in fact that it only runs once for the request even if you provide an array. Hope this answer is helpful for someone else..